# Log4j static logger

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j

i tried to make a static logger, with log4j. I got no error while reading the property file with `PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE);`, but if i want to log with for example debug

```
case DEBUG:
     System.out.println("debug");
     log.debug(message);
     break;
```

there is nothing happening. I make a system.out.println to find out if the code is reached, the println was printed. Can someone give me a hint, why the logger doesn't work??

Here is the full code.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.ErrorHandler;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.Filter;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class Logging {

    private static final String LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE = "/config/log4j.properties";
    private static Logging instance;
    private Logger log;

    public enum level {
        DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL
    };

    /**
     * Private Constructor for Logging.
     */
    private Logging() {
        PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of the Logger.
     */
    public static synchronized Logging getInstance() {

        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Logging(Logger.getLogger(Logging.class));
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Method for doing the logging of actions in the system.
     *
     * @param l The preciseness level of the logging.
     * @param message The message to print.
     */
    public void log(Logging.level l, String message) {
        switch (l) {
        case WARN:
            log.warn(message);
            break;
        case ERROR:
            log.error(message);
            break;
        case DEBUG:
            System.out.println("debug");
            log.debug(message);
            break;
        case FATAL:
            log.fatal(message);
            break;
        default:// INFO
            log.info(message);
            break;
        }
    }

    public Logging(Logger logger) {
        this();
        setLogger(logger);
    }

    private void setLogger(Logger log) {
        this.log = log;
    }
}
```

Hier is the log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C://loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: When you start up your app, what's your console output say?  Any warnings/errors in there?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the cause for this behavior is that you've configured your logger to show only `INFO` entries and above. Meaning that only `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR` and `FATAL` will be displayed.

Comment: As a side note: your class design is way over complicated. The traditional use of Log4j loggers is just define `private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CurrentClass.class);`, where *CurrentClass* is name of the class where this logger is defined. Then just log the events as required.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, the reason for your `DEBUG` messages not being shown is a faulty configuration.

To make it work, change your first line to the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
```

This will enable all messages whose level is higher or equal to `DEBUG` to be outputted to your file.

You can read all about it in the following manual: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html